# OOP-based calendar application printing weird ASCII characters?

Tags: c++, oop

I have an OOP-based calendar application I wrote in C++. Program works fine, but when I call `toString()` for my `Reminder`s and `Appointment`s (`Appointment` inherits from `Reminder`), I get really weird ASCII characters, and I am not sure why. After doing some digging online and on this website, it seems that it is because I am printing out something that "isn't there", but I am not sure what the culprit is. It probably has to do with my bad memory management (I am new to dynamic memory and C++ in general).

Basically
`Calendar` has a `vector<Day*> week`

`Day` has a `vector<Reminder*> errands`

`Reminder` has a string `name` detailing what it is; `Reminder(string name)`

and `Appointment` inherits from `Reminder`, but also has a `startTime` and an `endTime`; `Appointment(string name, int startTime, int endTime)` (24 hour based time)

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm> // just so case-insensitive string comparison

using namespace std;
//----------------------------------------------------
class Reminder
{
protected:
    string name;
    int beginningTime;
    int endingTime;

public:
    virtual string getReminder()
    {
        return name;
    }

    virtual string toString()
    {
        if (!getReminder().empty())
            cout << "Reminder - " << getReminder() << "\n";
    }

    Reminder()
    {
    }
    Reminder(string n)
    {
        name = n;
    }
};
//----------------------------------------------------
class Appointment : public Reminder
{
protected:
    string name;
    int beginningTime;
    int endingTime;

public:
    string getReminder()
    {
        return name;
    }

    int getBeginningTime()
    {
        return beginningTime;
    }

    int getEndingTime()
    {
        return endingTime;
    }

    string toString()
    {
        cout << "Appointment - " << getReminder() << " from " << getBeginningTime() << ":00 "
             << "to " << getEndingTime() << ":00\n";
    }

    Appointment()
    {
    }
    Appointment(string n, int b, int e)
    {
        name = n;
        beginningTime = b;
        endingTime = e;
    }
};
//----------------------------------------------------
class Day
{
protected:
    int date;
    string day;

public:
    vector<Reminder *> reminders;
    Day()
    {
    }
    Day(int d, string da)
    {
        date = d;
        day = da;
    }
    int getDate()
    {
        return date;
    }
    string getName()
    {
        return day;
    }

    void addAppointment(string newAppt, int b, int e)
    {
        Appointment *a = new Appointment(newAppt, b, e);
        reminders.push_back(a);
    }
    void addErrand(string newReminder)
    {
        Reminder *r = new Reminder(newReminder);
        reminders.push_back(r);
    }
    void removeErand(string removedReminder)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < reminders.size(); i++)
        {
            if (reminders[i]->getReminder() == (removedReminder))
            {
                reminders.erase(reminders.begin() + i);
            }
        }
    }
    string toString()
    {
        cout << getDate() << ". " << getName() << "(" << reminders.size() << " errands)";
    }
};
//----------------------------------------------------
class Calendar
{
private:
    string title;
    int numDays;
    Day startingDay;

public:
    vector<Day *> week;
    Calendar(string t, int n, Day da)
    {
        title = t;
        numDays = n;
        startingDay = da;
        if (startingDay.getName() == ("Monday") || startingDay.getName() == ("monday"))
        {
            Day *s = new Day(0, "Monday");
            week.push_back(s);
            for (int i = 1; i < numDays; ++i)
            {
                Day *d;
                if (i % 7 == 1)
                    d = new Day(i, "Tuesday");
                else if (i % 7 == 2)
                    d = new Day(i, "Wednesday");
                else if (i % 7 == 3)
                    d = new Day(i, "Thursday");
                else if (i % 7 == 4)
                    d = new Day(i, "Friday");
                else if (i % 7 == 5)
                    d = new Day(i, "Saturday");
                else if (i % 7 == 6)
                    d = new Day(i, "Sunday");
                else if (i % 7 == 0)
                    d = new Day(i, "Monday");
                week.push_back(d);
            }
        }
        else if (startingDay.getName() == ("Tuesday") || startingDay.getName() == ("tuesday"))
        {
            Day *s = new Day(0, "Tuesday");
            week.push_back(s);
            for (int i = 1; i < numDays; ++i)
            {
                Day *d;
                // same as above code but with different order, removed to be more concise 
                week.push_back(d);
            }
        }
        else if (startingDay.getName() == ("Wednesday") || startingDay.getName() == ("wednesday"))
        {
            Day *s = new Day(0, "Wednesday");
            week.push_back(s);
            for (int i = 1; i < numDays; ++i)
            {
                Day *d;
                // same as above code but with different order, removed to be more concise 
                week.push_back(d);
            }
        }
        else if (startingDay.getName() == ("Thursday") || startingDay.getName() == ("thursday"))
        {
            Day *s = new Day(0, "Thursday");
            week.push_back(s);
            for (int i = 1; i < numDays; ++i)
            {
                Day *d;
                // same as above code but with different order, removed to be more concise 
                week.push_back(d);
            }
        }
        else if (startingDay.getName() == ("Friday") || startingDay.getName() == ("friday"))
        {
            Day *s = new Day(0, "Friday");
            week.push_back(s);
            for (int i = 1; i < numDays; ++i)
            {
                Day *d;
                // same as above code but with different order, removed to be more concise 
                week.push_back(d);
            }
        }
        else if (startingDay.getName() == ("Saturday") || startingDay.getName() == ("saturday"))
        {
            Day *s = new Day(0, "Saturday");
            week.push_back(s);
            for (int i = 1; i < numDays; ++i)
            {
                Day *d;
                // same as above code but with different order, removed to be more concise 
                week.push_back(d);
            }
        }
        else if (startingDay.getName() == ("Sunday") || startingDay.getName() == ("sunday"))
        {
            Day *s = new Day(0, "Sunday");
            week.push_back(s);
            for (int i = 1; i < numDays; ++i)
            {
                Day *d;
                // same as above code but with different order, removed to be more concise 
                week.push_back(d);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Sorry, that is not a valid day. Exiting\n";
        }
    }
    void displayCalendar()
    {

        for (auto &d : week)
        {
            cout << d->toString() << '\n';
        }
    }
};
//----------------------------------------------------
int main()
{
    string name, startingDay;
    int choice, numDays, secondMenuChoice;

    cout << "Welcome to Calendar\n";
    cout << "1. Build a new Calendar\n2. Exit\n";
    cin >> choice;

    if (choice == 1)
    {
        cout << "Give your calendar a title: \n"; //TODO take space input
        cin.ignore();
        getline(cin, name);

        cout << "How many days should this calendar have?\n";
        cin >> numDays;
        if (numDays <= 0)
        {
            do
            {
                cout << "Sorry, your calender needs to have a positive number of days to display. Try again:\n";
                cin >> numDays;
            } while (numDays <= 0);
        }

        cout << "What day should this calendar start on? (Monday, Tuesday, ...)\n";
        cin >> startingDay;

        Calendar c(name, numDays, Day(0, startingDay));
        cout << "Your calendar has been created.\n";

        while (secondMenuChoice != 0)
        {
            cout << "\nWhat do you want to do?\n";
            cout << "1. Display whole calendar\n";
            cout << "2. Display a single day\n";
            cout << "3. Add an errand\n";
            cout << "4. Delete an errand\n";
            cout << "5. Save to a file\n";
            cout << "0. Exit\n";
            cin >> secondMenuChoice;

            switch (secondMenuChoice)
            {
            case 1:
                cout << "------------------------\nCalendar: " << name << "\n------------------------\n";
                c.displayCalendar();
                cout << "\n";
                break;
            case 2:
            {
                cout << "Select which day to display reminders for (0-" << c.week.size() << ")\n";
                int day;
                cin >> day;
                cout << "------------------------\n"
                     << "Reminders for " << c.week[day]->getDate() << ". " << c.week[day]->getName() << "\n------------------------\n";
                for (auto &a : c.week[day]->reminders)
                {

                    cout << a->toString();
                }
                cout << "------------------------\n";
                break;
            }
            case 3:
            {
                string errandName;
                int startTime, endTime, errandDay, choice;
                cout << "Enter 0 for Appointment or enter 1 for Reminder\n";
                cin >> choice;
                if (choice == 0)
                {
                    cout << "Enter which day you'd like to add the appointments (0-" << c.week.size() - 1 << ")\n";
                    cin >> errandDay;
                    cout << "Enter the appointments's name\n";
                    cin.ignore();
                    getline(cin, errandName);
                    cout << "Enter the appointments's start time (0-24)\n";
                    cin >> startTime;
                    cout << "Enter the appointments's end time (0-24)\n";
                    cin >> endTime;
                    c.week[errandDay]->addAppointment(errandName, startTime, endTime);
                }
                else if (choice == 1)
                {
                    cout << "Enter which day you'd like to add the reminder (0-" << c.week.size() - 1 << ")\n";
                    cin >> errandDay;
                    cout << "Enter the reminder's name\n";
                    cin.ignore();
                    getline(cin, errandName);

                    c.week[errandDay]->addErrand(errandName);
                }

                break;
            }
            case 4:
            {
                string errandName;
                int errandDay;
                cout << "Enter the name of the errand you'd like to delete\n";

                cin.ignore();
                getline(cin, errandName);
                cout << "Enter the day it's on (0-" << c.week.size() << ")\n";
                cin >> errandDay;
                int j = 0;
                for (auto &i : c.week[errandDay]->reminders)
                {
                    if (i->getReminder() == errandName)
                    {
                        c.week[errandDay]->reminders.erase(c.week[errandDay]->reminders.begin() + j);
                        break;
                    }
                    j++;
                }
            }
            break;
            case 5:
                // @todo write to a file
                break;
            case 0:
                cout << "Exiting\n";
                break;
            default:
                cout << "Try again\n";
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    else if (choice == 2)
    {
        cout << "Goodbye";
    }
}
```

Here is the output if I just want to display the Calendar

```
/*
Welcome to Calendar
1. Build a new Calendar
2. Exit
1
Give your calendar a title:
Calendar Test
How many days should this calendar have?
7
What day should this calendar start on? (Monday, Tuesday, ...)
Sunday
Your calendar has been created.

What do you want to do?
1. Display whole calendar
2. Display a single day
3. Add an errand
4. Delete an errand
5. Save to a file
0. Exit
1
------------------------
Calendar: Calendar Test
------------------------
0. Sunday(0 errands)@╬≡o
1. Monday(0 errands)@╬≡o
2. Tuesday(0 errands)@╬≡o
3. Wednesday(0 errands)@╬≡o
4. Thursday(0 errands)@╬≡o
5. Friday(0 errands)@╬≡o
6. Saturday(0 errands)@╬≡o
*/
```

Where does the `@╬≡o` come form?

In addition, when I add `Reminder`s to the days and print out the reminders on a day, this is what I get:

```
/*
Welcome to Calendar
1. Build a new Calendar
2. Exit
1
Give your calendar a title:
Calendar Test 2
How many days should this calendar have?
7
What day should this calendar start on? (Monday, Tuesday, ...)
Sunday
Your calendar has been created.

What do you want to do?
1. Display whole calendar
2. Display a single day
3. Add an errand
4. Delete an errand
5. Save to a file
0. Exit
3
Enter 0 for Appointment or enter 1 for Reminder
0
Enter which day you'd like to add the appointments (0-6)
0
Enter the appointments's name
Dentist
Enter the appointments's start time (0-24)
8
Enter the appointments's end time (0-24)
9

What do you want to do?
1. Display whole calendar
2. Display a single day
3. Add an errand
4. Delete an errand
5. Save to a file
0. Exit
3
Enter 0 for Appointment or enter 1 for Reminder
1
Enter which day you'd like to add the reminder (0-6)
0
Enter the reminder's name
Study For Test

What do you want to do?
1. Display whole calendar
2. Display a single day
3. Add an errand
4. Delete an errand
5. Save to a file
0. Exit
2
Select which day to display reminders for (0-7)
0
------------------------
Reminders for 0. Sunday
------------------------
Appointment - Dentist from 8:00 to 9:00
Y├j  §xüReminder - Study For Test
Y├j  §xü------------------------
*/
```

Why does my code output that weird `Y├j  §xü` before the `Study For Test` `Reminder` and the seperator?

Comment: Not checking your code well, it looks like you forgot to terminate your string by adding NUL.

Comment: And when you used your debugger to run your program, one line at a time, and inspect the values of all variables and data structures, as they change while the program runs, what did you see?

Comment: It looked like so, but actually there seems no strings to be manually terminated...?

Comment: Ah, you invoked *undefined behavior* by not using `return` statement in the non-void function `string toString()` in the class `Day`.

Comment: The polymorphism seems wholly unnecessary, and the inheritance is screwed up with repeating data as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You invoked *undefined behavior* by reaching at end of non-void functions without executing `return` statement in these functions:

(class `Reminder`)

```
    virtual string toString()
    {
        if (!getReminder().empty())
            cout << "Reminder - " << getReminder() << "\n";
    }
```

(class `Appointment`)

```
    string toString()
    {
        cout << "Appointment - " << getReminder() << " from " << getBeginningTime() << ":00 "
             << "to " << getEndingTime() << ":00\n";
    }
```

(class `Day`)

```
    string toString()
    {
        cout << getDate() << ". " << getName() << "(" << reminders.size() << " errands)";
    }
```

Instead of these, if you decided to print what are returned from the functions, it looks like you should use [`std::stringstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream) to build the strings and return them instead of directly printing them.

Add this:

```
#include <sstream>
```

and then each functions will be like this:

```
    virtual string toString()
    {
        std::stringstream ss;
        if (!getReminder().empty())
            ss << "Reminder - " << getReminder() << "\n";
        return ss.str();
    }
```

```
    string toString()
    {
        std::stringstream ss;
        ss << "Appointment - " << getReminder() << " from " << getBeginningTime() << ":00 "
             << "to " << getEndingTime() << ":00\n";
        return ss.str();
    }
```

(class `Day`)

```
    string toString()
    {
        std::stringstream ss;
        ss << getDate() << ". " << getName() << "(" << reminders.size() << " errands)";
        return ss.str();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Compiling this, I immediately get errors like these:

> test.cpp(278): error C4700: uninitialized local variable 'secondMenuChoice' used
> test.cpp(124): error C4716: 'Day::toString': must return a value
> test.cpp(25): error C4716: 'Reminder::toString': must return a value
> test.cpp(63): error C4716: 'Appointment::toString': must return a value

On top of that I see multiple instances like this:

```
Day *d;
week.push_back(d);
```

This will invoke undefined behavior, as soon as you try to use the values you pushed because you are pushing an uninitialized pointer.

A general advice would be that you shouldn't use vectors with raw pointers here, because you can instead push an object and not have to deal with dangling pointers or not freeing them.

```
Day d;
week.push_back(d);
```

An example is this line

```
reminders.erase(reminders.begin() + i);
```

where you remove the pointers from the vector, thus creating memory leaks, because you don't delete those pointers.